# laravel 8 , How to display data from a FORM with post method?

Tags: php, http-post, laravel-8

**my Route :**

```
Route::resource('/posts',PostsControllerWithAll::class);
```

**my form :**
i try to read the given data from this form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('PostsControllerWithAll@store') }}">
 @csrf
   <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter title">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**my controller :**

```
public function create()
{
    return view("posts.create");

}

public function store(Request $request)
   {
        return $request->all();
   }
```

**and this is my route list**

[route list image , please check the link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bRf8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the named route, like you show on your print screen.

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{ action('posts.store') }}">...</form>
```

To validated the fields values on store method, use dd($request->all()) this dump the variable and die, it's good to see what is expected.